# Linux system completely freezes "CPU Stuck for 22 seconds"/ Hardware Error?

Tags: linux, cpu, freeze, linux-kernel

I have got the issue of regular freezes on my ryzen 5 computer. It occurs across different distibutions and kernels.

The freezes occur mostly when trying to suspend the system to ram, but also changes with the display settings such as screen resolution or diabling of a monitor can cause freezes.
The cpu also reports something about being stuck when shutting down the pc.

When the freeze is due to display changes, the computer often freezes for several seconds, but starts working again after some time.

When I'm getting a freeze from a suspend though, the computer completely reboots and I get the picture related error message upon startup.
[suspend freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8SfI.jpg)

something like this:

```
[Hardware Error]: CPU 5: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000
```

The weird thing is that it seems to occur very randomly. When the system is freshly started, I don't get these issues.

**This is a kernel log I took from a freeze from suspending to ram with complete reboot:**

```
-- Journal begins at Wed 2020-12-30 15:47:51 CET, ends at Wed 2021-03-10 12:16:36 CET. --
Mär 09 21:51:56 pwrpc kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1615323116.616:528): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Mär 09 21:51:56 pwrpc kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from 7c:ff:4d:55:f7:49 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mär 09 21:51:56 pwrpc kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: sta 7c:ff:4d:55:f7:49 with macid 0 left
Mär 09 21:51:56 pwrpc kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: stop vif 80:91:33:7e:93:e5 on port 0
Mär 09 21:51:57 pwrpc kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: start vif 7a:ea:57:19:ee:68 on port 0
Mär 09 21:51:57 pwrpc kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: stop vif 7a:ea:57:19:ee:68 on port 0
Mär 09 21:51:57 pwrpc kernel: rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: start vif 80:91:33:7e:93:e5 on port 0
Mär 09 21:51:57 pwrpc kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

**this is what happens upon display changes (kernel log):**

```
-- Journal begins at Wed 2020-12-30 15:47:51 CET, ends at Tue 2021-03-09 19:35:28 CET. --
Mär 09 19:32:01 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                last message was failed ret is 0
Mär 09 19:32:04 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                failed to send message 145 ret is 0 
Mär 09 19:32:09 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                last message was failed ret is 0
Mär 09 19:32:12 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                failed to send message 146 ret is 0 
Mär 09 19:32:15 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                last message was failed ret is 0
Mär 09 19:32:17 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                failed to send message 148 ret is 0 
Mär 09 19:32:23 pwrpc kernel: amdgpu: 
                                last message was failed ret is 0
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s! [Xorg:3367]
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: Modules linked in: rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet mii tun ccm mousedev joydev btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth uas ecdh_generic usb_storage usbhid ecc dm_mod snd_hda_codec_realtek ext4 snd_hda_codec_generic rtw88_8822be rtw88_8822b ledtrig_audio rtw88_pci snd_hda_codec_hdmi rtw88_core nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat snd_hda_intel edac_mce_amd fat snd_intel_dspcfg crc16 mbcache soundwire_intel eeepc_wmi jbd2 soundwire_generic_allocation asus_wmi kvm_amd soundwire_cadence sparse_keymap amdgpu mac80211 video wmi_bmof snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core gpu_sched irqbypass ttm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_compress crypto_simd cryptd ac97_bus glue_helper k10temp snd_pcm_dmaengine rapl snd_pcm igb cec snd_timer snd syscopyarea pcspkr sp5100_tco sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt fb_sys_fops i2c_piix4 soundcore i2c_algo_bit rfkill dca rng_core libarc4 wmi gpio_amdpt pinctrl_amd gpio_generic mac_hid
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel:  acpi_cpufreq vboxnetflt(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxdrv(OE) drm pkcs8_key_parser fuse sg agpgart bpf_preload ip_tables x_tables btrfs blake2b_generic libcrc32c crc32c_generic xor raid6_pq crc32c_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 3367 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W  OEL    5.10.20-1-lts #1
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG STRIX B450-I GAMING, BIOS 3103 06/17/2020
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: RIP: 0010:delay_halt_mwaitx+0x1d/0x40
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: Code: 0f ae f1 c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 53 48 c7 c0 00 60 00 00 65 48 03 05 13 3d cf 5f 31 d2 48 89 d1 0f 01 fa <bb> ff ff ff ff b8 f0 00 00 00 b9 02 00 00 00 48 39 de 48 0f 46 de
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb0ba0084f4f0 EFLAGS: 00000246
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: RAX: ffff93e15ebc6000 RBX: 00004f8187de28e8 RCX: 0000000000000000
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000e10 RDI: 00004f8187de28e8
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: RBP: 0000000000000e10 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffb0ba0084f370
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: R10: ffffb0ba0084f368 R11: ffff93e17f32b268 R12: 0000000000000095
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 000000000000ffff R15: ffff93da51bce88c
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: FS:  00007f2ac269f940(0000) GS:ffff93e15ebc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: CR2: 000038cf6a17a000 CR3: 0000000129c9e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Mär 09 19:32:25 pwrpc kernel: Call Trace:
```

**TL;DR**
So in short, freezes are caused by different thigs, often mentioning something of a frozen CPU core.

Any idea what this might be?
Is there some kernel module I am missing here or might this be a hardware related defect?

Best regards

Comment: Another weird behaviour I have noticed after living with this horrendous problem for half a year / pretty much since I got this computer:
For some reason the system freezes when I have a browser opened. When I close them before suspending, it rarely freezes.